ASP.NET Core is logging "request unhandled" even though it is handled by my middleware
I have some middleware which sets a response status code, content type and content (with SendFileAsync) yet the log file contains a debug message from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics saying "Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code".
My code looks like this:
context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
await context.Response.SendFileAsync(filePath);

This behaviour appears to be driven this code:
var reachedPipelineEnd = httpContext.Items.ContainsKey(RequestUnhandledKey);

...

if (reachedPipelineEnd)
{
    LogRequestUnhandled(context);
}

And indeed the HTTP context contains this:

So my question is: what do I have to do for ASP.NET to consider the request is handled? I always thought setting the status code did that but not as far as this log message is concerned.
Obviously I could manually set this value to false but that is too hacky. What is the correct way?

The problem is that I was doing this at the start of my middleware Invoke method, to ensure this "fallback" middleware runs last in the pipeline:
await _next(context);
if (context.GetEndpoint() != null || context.Response.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
{
    return;
}
// Middleware does its stuff here

So the pipeline does indeed run to the end before I do anything, causing the "unhandled" flag to be set.
I did previously try the normal way with await _next at the end, but I had other problems with that so went this way. I will revisit that approach and rely on the placement of the Use... call to establish the right order.
Update
Now I remember the problem with that: nothing has set the status code to 404 yet, so my check whether anything has handled the request fails (status code is 200). Perhaps it's better to check for Response.ContentType == null.
